# How generate random word from real languages

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, words

How I can generate random word from real language?

Anybody know any API from internet with this functional?

For example I send http-request to 'ht_tp://www.any...api.com/getword?lang=**en**' and I get responce 'Town'.  Or 'Fast'. Or 'Received'... For example I send http-request to 'ht_tp://www.any...api.com/getword?lang=**ru**' and I get responce 'Ходить'.  Or 'Шапка'. Or 'Отправлено'... Any form (noun, adjective, verb etc...) of the words of the any language.

I find resource 'http://www.randomlists.com/random-words'. But this is not JSON format, only English, and don't any warranty work in long time.

Please any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824422/can-i-get-an-english-dictionary-word-list-somewhere   Download a word dictionary, stick in the databse and fetch a random record or read a random line from the file each time. This way you don't depend on 3rd party API and you can extend it in all the languages you can find words for.

Comment: Yes, I need words from all (or most) languages.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [the OpenOffice dictionaries](http://extensions.openoffice.org/). They come as extension (oxt), which is nothing different than a ZIP file. You may open them with 7zip or alike. Within you will find lots of files, interesting for you are the *.dic files. They will also contain resolutions or number words.

When you encounter something like `abandon/LdS` get rid of the `/LdS` this is used for hunspell.

Take these *.dic files use their name as key, put them into a database and pick a random word from there for a given language code.

**Update**

Older, but easier to access, [the archived hunspell dictionaries from OpenOffice](http://archive.services.openoffice.org/pub/mirror/OpenOffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/).

Answer (score -1):

This question can be viewed in two ways and therefore I give two answers:

- To collect words, I would run a spider on websites with known language (Wikipedia is a good starting point) and strip HTML tags.
- To *generate* words from a real language is trickier. Using statistics from the collected words, it is possible to use Markow chains that produces *statistically* real words. I have tried letter by letter generation, and that works poorly. It is probably a better approach to use syllable construction instead.

Comment: you right with both ways. But first way not applicable for my android app because this increase traffic from user's mobile devices. This is not clear way. Second way is hard. Also I think about use dictionary on all languages, but this need use own web-service (in case store dictionaries on site) or very-very increase size of local client's apps (in case store dictionaries on user's mobile devices).

Comment: @TapaSave You will not succeed with the second way if you do not succeed collecting data. About traffic: If you read web pages with much text like Wikipedia, you will get a good portion of words per amount of data. To reduce search depth, take only the pages articles mentioned on the title page and cache words locally, after a couple of runs you will have collected a log of words.

Comment: In this case I can get words from another languages when I will parse pages like Wiki. I can't determine which language the word belongs found. Second negative case: I can find abbreviations, acronyms, numbers, slang and another 'garbage' words.

Comment: If you stick to Wiki, you will know article language. Only use content from <div id="mw-content-text"> works for now if you skip the references section.